# How to create Custom Notification in android

Tags: android, notifications, android-custom-view

I need to create a custom notification instead of the default notification in android.
Current notification have a icon,heading and message like below image

[image]

I want it customise like this

[image]

how can i achieve this

Comment: Check here http://codeversed.com/expandable-notifications-android/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Notification views**

**Normal View** - A notification in normal view appears in an area that’s up to 64 dp tall. Even if you create a notification with a big view style, it will appear in normal view until it’s expanded.

```
Content title
Large icon
Content text
Content info
Small icon
Notification time
```

**Normal View Like**
[image]

**Big View** - A notification’s big view appears only when the notification is expanded, which happens when the notification is at the top of the notification drawer, or when the user expands the notification with a gesture.  Expanded notifications were first introduced in `Android 4.1 JellyBean [API 16]`.  `Expandable notifications` were designed to support rich notification style objects called `Notification.Style`.

**Big View Like**

[image]

Go to this link [expandable-notifications-android](http://codeversed.com/expandable-notifications-android/)

More information on official [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: What if there needs  to be custom layout ?

Answer (score 4):

I have create notification usingby following  http://developer.android.com/wear/notifications/creating.html

Add code for create notification.

```
// Specify the 'big view' content to display the long
// event description that may not fit the normal content text.
BigTextStyle bigStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
bigStyle.bigText(eventDescription);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_event)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFractory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.notif_background))
        .setContentTitle(eventTitle)
        .setContentText(eventLocation)
        .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_map,
                getString(R.string.map), mapPendingIntent)
        .setStyle(bigStyle);
```

Answer (score 3):

That's called [Expanded layouts](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) which is available right from Jelly Bean version.

There are 2 views of Notifications:

1. Normal View
2. Big View

A notification’s big view appears only when the notification is expanded, which happens when the notification is at the top of the notification drawer, or when the user expands the notification with a gesture.  Expanded notifications were first introduced in Android 4.1 JellyBean [API 16].

In your case, you just want to display big picture in notification, give [**Notification.BigPictureStyle**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigPictureStyle.html) a try:

```
Bitmap remote_picture = null;

// Create the style object with BigPictureStyle subclass.
NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notiStyle = new 
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
notiStyle.setBigContentTitle("Big Picture Expanded");
notiStyle.setSummaryText("Nice big picture.");

try {
        remote_picture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                (InputStream) new URL(sample_url).getContent());
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}

// Add the big picture to the style.
notiStyle.bigPicture(remote_picture);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use NotificationCompat  that need remoteview  . below i set my custom layout named
activity_downlaodactivity

```
NotificationManager manager =   (NotificationManager)       getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.activity_downlaodactivity);


   android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder    mBuilder =
            new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContent(contentView)

   manager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```