# How to use push notification like flipkart

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which when the merchant of the apps give any offers then it will give the push notification to the user like in flipkart,snapdeal.I dont know how to do that..any one have any idea about that.

Comment: Use this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101269/how-to-create-custom-notification-in-android) you achieve your target

Comment: no actually, the thing is i want that whenever merchant will enter any offers  for the users in their app, it will give push notifications for the user apps.

Comment: Then use FCM or GCM visit page

Answer (score 0):

use GCM notifications for this purpose..

use this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/